# Replacing property placeholders in externalIvyFile with project.properties in SBT 0.13?

Tags: sbt, ivy

I use SBT **0.13**.

I've an external Ivy file using `externalIvyFile(Def.setting(baseDirectory.value / "custom-name.xml"))` in `build.sbt`.

In the `ivy.xml` there are property placeholders in the form of `${branch}`. The values for these properties come from `project.properties`.

How do I tell sbt to use my `project.properties` to populate the placeholders?

Comment: Have you tried to put `project.properties` under `project` directory (next to `build.properties`)? It may work.

Comment: @Jacek Didn't work unfortunately. Thanks for the editing btw!

Comment: Not an answer, but useful for others who learn sbt - instead of using `externalIvyFile(baseDirectory( _ / "ivy.xml"))` use `externalIvyFile(baseDirectory.value / "ivy.xml")` instead. Could you update the question?

Comment: Edit done. The new syntax looks more expressive I'll admit. The previous one comes from the sbt [docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html#ivy-file-dependency-configuration) though.

Comment: Noticed it and...https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/1285.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

- rename your ivy.xml to ivy.xml.template
- ixy.xml.template and project.properties must be in base folder
- Add this to file base_folder/project/project/build.scala

.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.util.Properties
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import sbt._
import Keys._

object build extends Build {
  def readProperties(filename: String): Map[String, String] = {
    try {
      val prop = new Properties()
      prop.load(new FileInputStream(filename))
      prop.stringPropertyNames().map( k => (k,prop.getProperty(k))).toMap
    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        e.printStackTrace()
        Map()
    }
  }

  def processIvyXml(base: File): Seq[File] = {
    val properties = readProperties((base/"../project.properties").getAbsolutePath)
    val ivyXml: String = sbt.IO.read(base/"../ivy.xml.template")
    val result = properties.keys.foldLeft(ivyXml){
      (tmpXml,key) => tmpXml.replaceAll( "\\$\\{"+key+"\\}" , properties(key))
    }
    sbt.IO.write(base/"../ivy.xml",result)
    Seq()
  }

  lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).settings(
    resourceGenerators in Compile <+= (baseDirectory in Compile) map { base =>
      processIvyXml(base)
    }
  )
}
```

This file reads project.properties and ivy.xml.template before compiling the project definition and creates a customized ivy.xml populated with values from project.properties

Now just add ivy.xml to .gitignore and you are set.

The only thing to remember is that any time you modify the project.properties you must call reload on sbt console (or restart the sbt)

You can expand this to work for other files as well but I will leave that as an exercise to you.

Comment: Updated because I did something similar at the end. One question though. I would have expected that adding the processIvyXml to the resourceGenerators in Compile would prevent the need for a reload at each property change. Why is the reload still needed?

Comment: "base_folder/project/project/build.scala" -> one "project" too many maybe?

Comment: I have to admit, I can't decide if this is an acceptable answer or a hack ... I'll accept it before the bounty ends, if nothing more integrated to the sbt default features shows up.

Comment: ivy.xml.template and project.properties are not declared as resources to the inner project. Even if they were it would not work because once sbt completes compilation of the outermost project it doesn't check the inner ones for changes.

Comment: "base_folder/project/project/build.scala" is correct path. The point is to make a build for the build. Take a look at this: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html And yes, it is a hack :-) I love SBT because it allows a lot of freedom and hacks like this.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid code duplication, I created an SBT plugin for this: https://github.com/matthieus/sbt-ivy

Forks are more than encouraged as there are some hardcoded values in there.